# Method not allowed DELETE

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Hi I am running into a problem in that I am getting a 405 error for my delete request.  All the other request methods seem fine.  I have tagged the class with the @RestController annotation and have also tagged the delete method with the @ResponseBody annotation.  I am currently running my application in a docker container and can see from the logs

`WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'DELETE' not supported`

Here is my RestController class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<User>> getUsers() {
        Collection<User> users = userService.findAll();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(users);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<User> get(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        User user = userService.findOne(id);

        if(user == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<User> post(@RequestBody User user) {
        User createdUser = userService.create(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(createdUser);
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<User> put(@RequestParam(value = "id") long id, @RequestBody User editUser) {

        User user = userService.update(id, editUser);

        if(user == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id) {

        if(id == 0) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("what are you doing", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        userService.delete(id);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Successfully deleted user");
    }
}
```

and here is the error I am getting from when I try to send a DELETE request to the server

```
{"timestamp":1477839973484,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'DELETE' not supported","path":"/api/user/1"}
```

here is the unit test method:

```
@Test
public void deleteUser() throws Exception {

    String uri = "/api/user";
    long id = 2;

    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete(uri, id)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();

    String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

    int status = result.getResponse().getStatus();

    Assert.assertEquals("failure - expected HTTP status 200", 200, status);
    Assert.assertTrue("failure - expected HTTP response body to have a value", content.trim().length() == 0);

    User user = userService.findOne(1);

    Assert.assertNull(user);
}
```

Comment: Are other methods GET & PUT working ?

Comment: @javaguy yes they are, I have written unit tests for these which they all pass and give me a response code 200, just delete is giving me a 405

Comment: Check latest class file loaded if delete is added at the end

Comment: @javaguy what do you mean by that?  I am quite new to java as I thought I'd start new project to learn.

Comment: Check when the class file is compiled to find that it is latest

Comment: What URL is your unit test for delete using?

Comment: Hi @StephenC I will update my post with the unit test method for delete

Comment: @GhostCat No need to be so condescending. I didn't understand javaguy _check latest class file loaded_ comment either until he translated that to "check the compiled class". It has nothing to do with skill level. I see how you were trying to help OP with your comment but honestly, the last two sentences were just unnecessary IMO.